# Multi language database encoding in search engine

Tags: php, mysql, database, internationalization

I have a database(Mysql) in which I store more then 100 000 keywords with keyword in different languages. So an example if I have three colums [id] [turkish (utf8_turkish_ci)] [german(utf8)]

The users could enter a german or a turkish word in the search box. If the user enters a german word all is fine so it prints out the turkish word but how to solve it with the turkish one. I ask because each language has its own additional characters like ä ü ö ş etc.

So should I use

```
mb_convert_encoding
```

to convert the string but then how to check if it is a german or turkish string  I think that would be to complex. Or is the encoding of the tables wrong?

Stuck now so how to implement it so the user could enter keyword of both languages words

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues to solve to make this work correctly.

**First**, you've chosen the `utf8` character set to hold all your text. That is a good choice. If this is a new-in-2016 application, you might choose the `utf8mb4`  character set instead.  Once you have chosen a character set your users should be able to read your text.

**Second**, for the sake of searching and sorting (`WHERE` and `ORDER BY`) you need to choose an appropriate collation for each language. For modern German, `utf8_general_ci`  will work tolerably well. `utf8_unicode_ci` works a little better if you need standard lexical ordering. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

For modern Spanish, you should use `utf8_spanish_ci`. That's because in Spanish the N and Ñ characters are not considered the same.  I don't know whether the general collation works for Turkish.

Notice that you seem to have confused the notions of character set and collation in your question. You've mentioned a collation with your Turkish column and a character set with your German column.

You can explicitly specify character set and collation in queries. For example, you can write

```
    WHERE _utf8 'München' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = table.name;
```

In this expression, `_utf8 'München'` is a character constant, and

```
   constant COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = table.name
```

is a query specifier which includes an explicit collation name. Read this.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html

**Third**, you may want to assign a *default* collation to each language specific column. Default collations are baked into indexes, so they'll help accelerate searching.

**Fourth**, your users will need to use an appropriate input method (keyboard mapping, etc) to present data to your application. Turkish-language users hopefully know how to type Turkish words.

Comment: I forgot to write that I save the turkish words with replacing the special characters with the unicode so I maybe I use strtr() to detect a character in a string to replace it with the unicode one to send the query

Comment: I mean I use strtr() with an array